# How to install non gui version of ubuntu 21

Tags: server, virtualbox

I have downloaded ubuntu 21 server version instead of desktop version iso file, hoping I can install without GUI.

So, I tried testing it on virtualbox, installed "Minimal features" selected.

But still I got the GUI version installed.

I tried uninstalling the gui with below command , but didn't help.

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Ubuntu has the main *deb* based products which are *year.month* in format, they are available for desktops & servers, but also has a different product range that is *snap* only and uses the *year* format which are designed for *headless* server use (devices, appliances or cloud use is the intended use).  There is no Ubuntu 21; the *snap* only products only come out in *even* years so you may have a *forgery* or have your facts wrong.  I'd check what you actually have; as all releases using the *year* range are for servers and *headless* operation and don't use `apt` commands (that's for *deb*)

Comment: Ubuntu server version does **not** install a desktop. https://ubuntu.com/download/server and has a 21.04 manual install. Please use that

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-server#1-overview